# org.hibernate.MappingException when using tablePerConcreteClass inheritance strategy in Grails v3.2.9

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm using grails v3.2.9

I have 2 domain classes(class `A` and class `B`) having some common properties. I have created a new class `C`, extracted common properties from `A` and `B` to `C` and made `A` and `B` to extend `C` as shown bellow:

```
class A extends C {
   String x
   static constraints = {}
}

class B extends C {
   String y
   static constraints = {}
}

class C {
   String z

   static constraints = {}

   static mapping = {
    tablePerConcreteClass true
   }
}
```

I want `C` to reflect JPA `@MappedSuperClass`, so I have checked the [documentation for grails v3.1.12](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.12/guide/GORM.html) and found about `tablePerConcreteClass` which seems to be exactly what I need, however in [documentation for grails v3.2.9](http://docs.grails.org/3.2.9/guide/GORM.html) there is noting about `tablePerConcreteClass` and I'm not sure even whether that strategy is supported by grails 3.2.9 or not.

Anyway I have tried to use `tablePerConcreteClass` with my grails v3.2.9 and got the following exception:

> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect does not support sequences

I have seen some solutions to create the parent class in `src/groovy` package and make it abstract, but that is not what I need, I want the parent class to be a domain class as well to be able to write the constraints in a single place as well.

UPDATE *****
Also I have found out that if I make `C` abstract, put a relation into it and make `A` to extend it as follows:

```
abstract class C {
   Bar bar

   static constraints = {}
}

class A extends C {
   String x
   static constraints = {}
}
```

then the artificial property `barId`, allowing to get the id of the relation without loading it, is not created by grails, so using
  `A.get(1).barId` results into `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException`. 
In contrast in case if we put `Bar bar` relation into the subclass `A`, then the `barId` artificial property is created, so please mention about the solution to this problem if any.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an abstract parent class and still write the constraints in a single place.

For example, you could put C into src/main/groovy as such:

```
@grails.gorm.dirty.checking.DirtyCheckDirtyCheck
abstract class C {
    String z

    static constraints = {}
}
```

Then in A and B, your constraints block would just look like:

```
static constraints = {
    importFrom C
}
```

You can even add additional constraints after the `importFrom` line if A and B might each have different additional constraints that do not exist in C.

Comment: I typically do not use the artificial 'id' properties, so I don't have any answer for that!  Hopefully someone else on here will be able to help.  Don't forget to import your constraints as well, or they will not be applied!